# How can i add images to the react-native-layout-grid? There are no props mentioned specifically in the Github repository

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using the react-native-layout-grid package for displaying a grid layout. I want to add images in the grid layout instead of text/string. How can i do it?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import GridLayout from 'react-native-layout-grid';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  renderGridItem = (item) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <View style={styles.flex} />
      <Text style={styles.name}>
        {item.name}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );

  render() {
    const items = [];
    for (let x = 1; x <= 30; x++) {
      items.push({
        name: `Grid ${x}`
      });
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Grid Layout
        </Text>
        <View style={styles.flex}>
          <GridLayout
            items={items}
            itemsPerRow={3}
            renderItem={this.renderGridItem}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 ///styles///
});
```

### I need to add images instead of string texts being passed into props.Is there any way to do so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In renderGridItem add the images
Eg:---

```
 renderGridItem = (item) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <View style={styles.flex} />
<Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}}
        />
      <Text style={styles.name}>
        {item.name}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
```

working eg: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/petrified-tortillas

Comment: How about if I want to open a particular grid on press?

Comment: You have to wrap the image in  "TouchableOpacity" tag and on press call the function which you need

renderGridItem = (item) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{console.log(item)}}>
      <View style={styles.flex} />
      <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'}}
        />
      <Text style={styles.name}>
        {item.name}
      </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

eg: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/petrified-tortillas

Comment: Is there any way to display different images in the grids? E.g: different images in different grids. I tried placing mutliple uri's but it gets over rided by the uri defined last.

Comment: In grid layout you need to provide the data to render so in "items={data}" in grid layout pass the array data eg. data = [{name:'1', url: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png'},{name:'2', url:'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png'},{name:'3', url:'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2.png'}]
Working example: snack.expo.io/@msbot01/petrified-tortillas

Comment: do we define the array data in renderGridItem?

Comment: If your data is not changing then put this in a variable. If data is changing then put this in state variable and when data changes update the state variable